# Need to convert an array to Integer for a MySQL query in a Rails API

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a piece of code which fetches the list of ids of users I follow.

`@followed = current_user.followed_user_ids`

It gives me a result like this `[11,3,24,42]`

I need to add these to NOT IN mysql query.
Currently, I am getting `NOT IN ([11,3,24,42])` which is throwing an error. I need `NOT IN (11,3,24,42)`

This is a part of a `find_by_sql` statement, so using `where.not` is not possible for me in this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 4:

```
@followed = current_user.followed_user_ids # @followed = [11,3,24,42]
@not_followed = User.where.not(id: @followed)
```

This should generate something like `select * from users where id not in (11,3,24,42)`

As you comment, you are using `find_by_slq` (and that is available in all rails versions). Then you could use the `join` method:

```
query = "select * from users where id not in (#{@followed.join(',')})"
```

This would raise mysql errors if `@followed` is blank, the resulting query would be

```
select * from users where id not in ()
```

To solve this whiout specifiying aditional if statements to your code, you can use:

```
query = "select * from users where id not in (0#{@followed.join(',')})"
```

Your normal queries would be like:

```
select * from users where id not in (01,2,3,4)
```

but if the array is blank then would result in

```
select * from users where id not in (0)
```

which is a still valid sql statement and is delivering no results (which might be the expected situation in your scenario).

Comment: Thanks. But, the rest of the query is written using find_by_sql. It goes something like 
@people = User.find_by_sql("Select ....................ON u.id = r.user_id WHERE u.id NOT IN 
    (#{@followed}) GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY order_index DESC LIMIT 30;"). How do I use your code in this?

Comment: then use `@followed.join(",")`. That might give you problems if @followed is a blank array. To solve that you could write `NOT IN (0#{@followed.join(',')})`, resulting in `NOT IN (0)` if the array is blank.

Comment: @lokesh please add those details to your question.

Comment: A much more secure variant in older versions is to use prepared statements: `User.where("id NOT IN (?)", @followed)`. This uses the built-in escaping functions and ensures that there are not even accidental SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
@followed = [11,3,24,42] 
User.where('id not in (?)', @followed)
```

Comment: Thanks. But, the rest of the query is written using find_by_sql. It goes something like @people = User.find_by_sql("Select ....................ON u.id = r.user_id WHERE u.id NOT IN (#{@followed}) GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY order_index DESC LIMIT 30;"). How do I use your code in this?

Comment: maybe to use `User.joins('INNER JOIN ...').where('...').group('').limit(30).order('order_index DESC')`. Maybe you should take a look in the [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and try to find what is the most proper for you